# Connect to Internet domain from LAN

Tags: proxy, dns, apache2, lamp, lan

I'm struggling to iron out some webserver configuration since I've moved back home. I used to access my domain, let's say www.domain.com for this inquiry, from any network at university. Since moving home I've had to access the domain from its LAN IPV4 address.

I checked a few questions on this website and others, and have heard off-handed references to using DNS servers and/or a proxy for this issue, which I would love to do, but have had a very hard time working this out, and I don't want to start changing my LAN settings without having a solid understanding of what I need to do. How could I set up either a DNS or Proxy to fix this?

Comment: Every time you access a host by name (e.g. point your browser at `http :// www.domain.com`) you're using DNS.  The main purpose of DNS is to map hostnames to IP addresses.  Whatever you have at home - you're using DNS.  It sounds like the problem is that your university's DNS server knew about your webserver at the university.  Your DNS client at home is configured to use a different DNS server ... a server that DOESN'T know about whatever webserver (host) you're trying to reach.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. Webserver was on a different subnet from the router and was causing it to be unreachable from internet domain name